# PHP looping through records very slow

Tags: php, mysql, loops, pdo, query-optimization

I'm using PDO. So I have a statement that prepares a query to select a bunch of records. Example:

```
   //select duplicates
   $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT Name COUNT( * ) AS CNT
            FROM  `Test`
            GROUP BY Name
            HAVING CNT > 1');

   $stmt2 = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Test2 WHERE TName = ?');
```

Note that I do need all data selected, not certain columns. The table contains 5k records, sometimes more. I need to select all 5k records and for each of them I need to execute another query to select something else.

```
   $arr = array();
   while ($row = $stmt->fetch(DB::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       $stmt2->execute($row['Name']);
       $arr[] = $stmt2->fetchAll(DB::FETCH_ASSOC);
   }
```

I know I can use joins but for my case joins will not work, because I need to loop through the data and execute stmt2 for each stmt1 row.

When I run this it takes up to 10-15 minutes which I can't allow, I need it to be faster. Can anyone tell me what the problem is? 5k records does not seem that much to loop through.

```
      STMT1 returns up to 5.5k records
```

I need data for each duplicate returned:

Comment: What is you second query in execute?

Comment: Do you have proper indexes on the tables you're querying?

Comment: yes i do use indexes and i updated the content of second query

Comment: "but for my case joins will not work" - I highly doubt it. Based on your code, joins are exactly what you need. And it's slow because on one page load, you're executing **five thousand queries** per page load, since you execute one query per record. That's absurd.

Comment: but the actual code im using will not be able to join since im selecting the duplicates and for each duplicate i need to run the code

Comment: @Giorgi - Nobody can properly help you if you don't explain your problem clearly and provide the code (and db schema in this case) that you're looking at.

Comment: Make sure Test2 has an index starting with the TName column.

Comment: This is the so-called [n+1 problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem), you are running 5.5k + 1 queries on every page request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Joins won't work? HIGHLY HIGHLY doubtful:

```
SELECT test2.*, count(test.name) AS cnt
FROM test
LEFT JOIN test2 ON test2.id = test.id
GROUP BY test.name
HAVING (cnt > 1)
```

another try, given the OP's troubles:

```
SELECT *
FROM test2
WHERE name IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT name
   FROM test
   GROUP BY name
   HAVING (count(*) > 1)
)
```

Comment: i tried this, it works but it does not return records for both of the records, it only returns 1 record when i need both records i mean both duplicates

Comment: still taking long the second one seems to be the solution but its taking really long time i've been waiting for it to return rows for over 5 mins already

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you can't use JOINS, create a stored procudure, which will take an id as argument and return the data you need.

You can also use dictionary encoding for your `Name`, because operations with integers are much more faster.